# how to throw an error in a $http promise

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I have an angular service that wraps my rest api calls and returns a $http promise.

My question is how do I throw an error so that a promise that triggers the .error method gets called?  I don't want to just throw error since I want it to use the .success/.error in the calling function rather than doing a try catch block around it.

```
myFunction: function(foo)
   if (foo) {
      return $http.put(rootUrl + '/bar', {foo: foo});
   }
   else {
      //what do I return here to trigger the .error promise in the calling function
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First inject the $q-service in your service. Then in your else:

```
else {
     var deferred = $q.defer();
     deferred.reject("reject reason, foo was false");
     return deferred.promise;
}
```

Not as clever as Blazemonger's, but its quick to do.

Comment: I get .success ... is not a function from the calling controller.  do I have to define a success as well and just have it empty ?

Comment: the promise returned have the normal then-function and also a catch-function. catch is short hand for then(null, errorcallback), which is i guess what you want. then is as you might know: then(success, error, notify)

Comment: You can simply do `$q.reject("reject reason, foo was false");`, no reason to create the promise instance here.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need `$q.defer()`. And `else` too. You can use reject directly:

```
myFunction: function(foo) {
    if (foo) {
        return $http.put(rootUrl + '/bar', {foo: foo});
    }

    return $q.reject("reject reason");
}
```

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#reject

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to [create your own promise using `$q`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q). Here's how I did something similar in a recent project:

```
app.service('allData', ['$http','$q',function($http,$q) {
    return {
        getJson: function() {
            return $q(function(resolve, reject) { // return a promise
                $http.get('/path/to/data.json', {cache:true})
                    .success(function(data) {
                        if (angular.isArray(data)) { // should be an ordered array
                        // or any other test you like that proves it's valid
                            resolve(data);
                        } else {
                            reject("Invalid JSON returned");
                            console.log(data);
                        };
                    })
                    .error(function(data) {
                        reject("Invalid data returned");
                        console.log(data);
                    });
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

And in my controller:

```
allData.getJson().then(function(json) {
    // success, do something with the json
}, function(reason) { // failure, .getJson() had some kind of error
    alert('Sorry, unable to retrieve data from the server.')
    console.error(reason);
});
```

Comment: if the controller is calling it via  the convention .success().error() will it still work or would I need to define the success and error functions in the promise?  is success.error() considered deprecated or legacy?  should I switch to the .then() pattern?

Answer (score 0):

You can raise or throw a custom error using `throw new Error ("custom error")`.

For http:

```
http.get('url').toPromise().then (result =>{
  throw new Error ("My Custom Error") // New Custom error  New is optional w
}).catch(err => {
  throw  err
}); // catch will catch any error occur while http call
```